# Call a method from a class on something created by a different method in the same class?

Tags: python, class

I would like to call a method from a class on something created by another method in the class. How would I do this?

For example, I've just created a class called call me, and would like to use the result of the `subtract` method in the `add` method.

```
class call_me(object):

   def __init__(self, x, y):
         self.x = 5
         self.y = 10

   def subtract(self):
        difference = self.y - self.x
        return difference

   def add(self.subtract,second_number):
        # code to add the difference returned by subtract to the second number.
```

How would I add a second number to the difference returned by subtract?  Is there a way I could pass `difference` to `add`?

Comment: `self.subtract() + second_number`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def add(self, second_number):
    difference = self.substract()
    return difference + second_number
```

Comment: That answers my question. Your comment is unclear. It literally means: if I did understand your question (which you did), then edit it more...    It seems like you would want the opposite.

Comment: Because your question contains the comment `# code to add the two numbers, x and y...`